# Passing parameter to controller action from a Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

Is there anything wrong with this html? I want to have a link in the masterpage to navigate to "CreateParts" view. I have action 'CreateParts'  which have a parameter parentPartId in the controller 'PartList'.

```
<li id="taskAdminPartCreate" runat="server">
                                    <%= Html.ActionLink("Create New Part", "CreateParts", "PartList", new { parentPartId = 0 })%></li>
```

My controller action is like

```
public ActionResult CreateParts(int parentPartId)
    {
        HSPartList objHSPart = new HSPartList();
        objHSPart.Id = parentPartId;
        return View(objHSPart);
    }
```

When I click on 'Create New Part' in the menu in SiteMaster, I get exception. Please help me out of this.

Comment: Adding the exception to the question would be nice :)

Comment: rouen, can you help with best practices in asp.net mvc

Comment: that is not best practice, that is fundamental concept. Learn, what runat=server is doing in WebFroms, and why it is not needed in MVC. I recommend starting with some reading of "background" stuff like patterns behind WebForm and MVC

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You are using incorrect overload. You should use this overload

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

And the correct code would be

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Create New Part", "CreateParts", "PartList", new { parentPartId = 0 }, null)%>
```

Note that extra parameter at the end.
For the other overloads, visit [LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx). As you can see there is no `string, string, string, object` overload that you are trying to use.

Comment: You are great @archill . You saved a lot of time, thanks

Comment: Thanks, i was missing null.

Answer (score 10):

You are using the incorrect overload of ActionLink. Try this

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Create New Part", "CreateParts", "PartList", new { parentPartId = 0 }, null)%>
```

Answer (score 9):

Addition to the accepted answer:

if you are going to use

```
 @Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { @id = idValue, @secondParam= = 2 },null)
```

this will create actionlink where you can't create new custom attribute or style for the link.

However, the 4th parameter in ActionLink extension will solve that problem. Use the 4th parameter for customization in your way.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { @id = idValue, @secondParam= = 2 }, new { @class = "btn btn-info", @target = "_blank" })
```