# Use Action link and query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use an actionlink to call a controller. My URL is 
`localhost:16252/Concert/Index/9`.

I want to call create controller and send id (9) to the controller. How to access the id (9) from address bar by actionlink?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "Access to the id(9) from address bar by actionlink"? You use `Html.ActionLink()` to print an URL to HTML, no address bar involved there. Are you asking how to read this ID in your controller code once someone clicks the action link? Anyway see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293934/passing-parameter-to-controller-action-from-a-html-actionlink

Comment: @dev don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: Id value in the address bar is not always 9
For example index/10 index/31 index/105
How to send id value to create control?

Answer (score 0):

ActionLink has one overload that allows you to specify routevalues
MSDN Link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "Action", "Controller", new {Id= 9}, null)
```

Comment: Id value in the address bar is not always 9
For example index/10 index/31 index/105
How to send id value to create control?

Comment: @AliRezaii that is clear but you can pass a varible there, and if you need more help we need to see your view

Comment: I Wrote this code '                @Html.ActionLink("تعریف طبقات", "Create", new { id = Request.QueryString["id"] }, new { @class = "css_addConcertLink" })
'

Answer (score 0):

For Passing from View you have to use overload which takes parameter of RouteValueDictionary:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text","MyAction", "My", new {id= 9},null)
```

and in your controller:

```
public class MyController
{

    public ActionResult MyAction(int id)
    {
        // do something
        return View();
    }
}
```

Using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) of `Html.ActionLink()`

Comment: Thought the same thing initially but i think that what you're using in this example is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070(v=vs.118).aspx) and the first param is the LinkText, and second is the Action so no controller there,

Comment: @Toby corrected , we have to use this overload:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: Id value in the address bar is not always 9
For example index/10 index/31 index/105
How to send id value to create control?

Comment: @AliRezaii you can pass variable there

Comment: pass variable? I Wrote this code but it's not solution new{ id=request.querysreint["id"]}