# ASP.NET adding id to razor ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need razor to generate a href links. This code works fine:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Questions", "Questions", "SectionPartials")
```

How do I set an id element to the a href tag? I already tried:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Questions", "Questions", "SectionPartials", new { id= "new-link" })
```

Which adds a id to the a href, but the navigations won't work anymore. This also gives a error in the code (but does compile tho)

**Server error:**
[image]

**Code error**
[image]

Coudn't find any more information on this issue.. If there is some information missing (like controller/view(?)), I am happy to add those!

Thanks

Comment: You need to add a null parameter before your `new { id = "new-link" }` parameter, as you can see in Intellisense.

Comment: its weird when you say that you could not find any solution for this question.. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293934/passing-parameter-to-controller-action-from-a-html-actionlink) , [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152575/pass-parameter-to-controller-from-html-actionlink-mvc-4) and there are many more. All this i got with a Google search..

Comment: @Vini I apologize for not good search, I think because I am new on ASP.NET so I didn't know how to search more than I did

Comment: Being new to a technology doesnt have anything to do with searching. Anyways you got an answer. So no issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The desired `LinkExtensions.ActionLink` method signature is:

> public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(   this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>     string linkText,    string actionName,  object routeValues,     object
>   htmlAttributes )

So, your current `new { id= "new-link" }` is passed as the `routeValues` parameter. You need to pass it as the `htmlAttributes` instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Questions", "Questions", "SectionPartials", null, new { id= "new-link" });
```

Or (using named parameters):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Questions", "Questions", "SectionPartials", htmlAttributes: new { id= "new-link" });
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)

Comment: Hey Thanks for response, answer already was given but the extra explanation is really userfull!! (cant approve for 8 min, i will approve this one in a couple of minutes)!

Answer (score 3):

Try this because you need to ignore `routeValues` if you don't have some additional parameters:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Questions", "Questions", "SectionPartials", null, new { id= "new-link" })
```

or:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Questions", "Questions", "SectionPartials",  htmlAttributes : new { id= "new-link" })
```

Comment: Thanks for response, This is the answer and I wanted to ask where the null stands for, but that questions is already answered! Big thanks for fast response

Comment: @JimVercoelen you are welcome