# ASP.NET give parameter to ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net, what I really want is to give a parameter to an ActionResult.

I want somtehing like this (I dont know if this is possible)

```
Sudoku s = new Sudoku();
//  SudokuClass has a property -> public int[,] MyFields {get;set;}

 public ActionResult Index(int value) 
 {    
    if(value == 1)
    {
        myGame.Create();
        s.MyFields = myGame.GameField();
    }

    if(value == 2)
    {
        myGame.Cheat();
        s.MyFields = myGame.GameField(); 
    }

    if(value == 3)
    // some code

    return View(s);
}
```

MyCode is Index.cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cheat", "Index")
```

What i want is: if I click on the actionlink "Cheat", that i can give number 2 so the Cheat Method will start, and update s.MyFields;

The other code for displaying the fields I have omitted. I can get the fields show on the webpage when I use s.MyFields = mygame.GetFields(). So thats not the problem, the problem is how can I "Update" this when I Click on cheat.

Comment: i cannot test it now, but it should be someting like:
`@Html.ActionLink("Cheat", "Index", new { value = 2 })`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293934/passing-parameter-to-controller-action-from-a-html-actionlink

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cheat", "Index", new { value = 2})
```

Or any number you want to pass from your View.

Comment: I did not understand, what do you mean by "it makes a new HomeController"? Could you provide more details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99804/discussion-between-pedro-benevides-and-m1o).