# Is it possible to pass a parameter through @Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, parameters, html.actionlink

I need to use the same view, but have different data based on what button the user selects show up in the table. I would like to do this through just passing a parameter through the html.actionlink.

This is what i have currently in the View

```
 <li id="liOpenJobs">@Html.ActionLink("All Jobs", "AllJobs", "AdminJobs", new { filter = "All" })</li>
```

Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AllJobs(string filter)
    {
        if (PCSSession.Current.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var jobs = new JobRepository();
            var model = new JobsHistoryViewModel();
            if(filter == "All")
            {
                model.jobHistory = jobs.GetAllJobs("alljobs");
            }


            return View(model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("AdminLogin", "AdminLogin");

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068(v=vs.118).aspx) of the `ActionLink` helper method.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

The fourth parameter is the route values object and that will be used to generate the querystring items for the anchor tag's `href` attribute value. The fifth parameter is htmlAttributes. If you do not have any, simply pass `null`

```
@Html.ActionLink("All Jobs", "AllJobs", "AdminJobs", new { filter = "All" }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Some Jobs", "AllJobs", "AdminJobs", new { filter = "some"}, null)
```

This will generate HTML markup for anchor tags with `href` values like this

`/AdminJobs/AllJobs?filter=All` and `/AdminJobs/AllJobs?filter=some`

Comment: thanks, just found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293934/passing-parameter-to-controller-action-from-a-html-actionlink